# Laravel 5.2 Unit Testing Repository with Mocking "does not have method"

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, mockery

In Laravel 5.2, I want to unit test my Eloquent User Repository.

```
class EloquentUserRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function oneUser($id)
    {
        return $this->user->oneUser($id);
    }
}
```

My test looks like below, with mocking the interface:

```
class EloquentUserRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->user = factory(User::class, 1)->create(['name' => 'foo']);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_fetch_an_user()
    {

        $mock = Mockery::mock('App\Repositories\Interfaces\UserRepositoryInterface')
        ->shouldReceive('oneUser')
        ->once()
        ->with($this->user->id)
        ->andReturn('foo');

        App::instance(App\Repositories\EloquentUserRepository::class, $mock);
        $userRepository = App::make(App\Repositories\EloquentUserRepository::class);

        $this->assertEquals('foo', $userRepository->oneUser($this->user->id)->name);

    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
ErrorException: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Mockery\Expectation' does not have a method 'oneUser'
```

I expect a simulated object that has the method oneUser, but it returns Mockery\Expectation. What do I wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a new instance of EloquentUserRepository is made, a new user model is created. When you then call the oneUser method for the EloquentUserRepository class a method with the same name is called but on the user model. Therefore it's the user model you need to mock, not the UserRepositoryInterface.

You need to create a new instance of the EloquentUserRepository and send in the user model mock as an argument when it's created as shown below:

```
class EloquentUserRepositoryTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $userMock;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->userMock = Mockery::mock('User');
        $this->userMock->id = 1;
    }

    /** @test */
    public function it_fetch_an_user()
    {
        $this->userMock->shouldReceive('oneUser')->with($this->userMock->id)->andReturn('foo');

        $userRepository = App::make(App\Repositories\EloquentUserRepository::class, array($this->userMock));

        $this->assertEquals('foo', $userRepository->oneUser($this->userMock->id));
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Mockery::close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a comment, I doubt this is the right answer. When you mock the model `User`, it means that for example one day if you want to switch out Eloquent; you will need to refactor your test and remove the model `User` with something like `MongoUser`. This contradicts with the repository pattern. My understanding is that you shouldn't have to refactor your tests when switching the implementation of an interface.

Comment: As an addition to my previous comment. I have scoured the web and smart people tend to suggest that we should not test repositories. We should rather write integration tests to test if our repository calls work.  I think they have a point. Please see url url `https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/phpunit-testing-repositories`

Good luck. Please also remember: `Brilliance is evenly distributed.`